# Spacebar locked - typing spaces constantly

Tags: keyboard

I have a user with a spacebar issue. On Windows 7, the spacebar randomly starts acting like it's being pushed and held down. This applies to the EliteBook 8570p.

It doesn't look like a hardware issue because logging a user off Windows stops it for some time, but then it starts again. I've turned off the sticky keys option and pressing anything (<kbd>esc</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>spacebar</kbd>) does not stop the spacebar from typing spaces. It only stops when I push <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd> together, but when I release, it types spaces again.

Comment: Have you tried clean boot or safe mode ? Remove any software that you installed around the time when this problem started.

Comment: Clean the keyboard.

Comment: Strangest thing - this started happening to me today. Twice now I've had to sign out and/or restart the computer. This is Windows 10 on a ThinkPad Yoga Pro which in general never has any issues. Super funky...

Answer (score 2):

Actually, in my opinion this IS a hardware problem. Because it is a random/intermittent problem, determining a definite cause is often times difficult. What seems to work and what doesn't isn't always what you think nor is it always consistent.

I'd say that either one or both of the support bars and/or one or both or the scissor mechanisms under the space bar have been dislodged causing the spacebar not to move freely and/or the the switch underneath is damaged or dirty (probably damaged as the switches in Elitebooks are encapsulated in a rubber boot).

There is a YouTube video posted by mr82020674 that is titled "Tutorial: How to remove and replace keys on an HP Elitebook Laptop in 1080P" which shows what the mechanisms under the keyboard look like.

There is a service manual for the EliteBook 8570p at HP's Support Center (do a search for "EliteBook 8570p service manual"). In it you will find instructions on how to remove the keyboard assembly and part numbers should you need to replace it.

If the spacebar key does not seem to be sticking due to the support bars and/or scissor mechanism(s), I might recommend removing the keyboard, soaking it in hot water for 15 minutes to soften up any crud, THOROUGHLY spraying the keyboard with hot water to wash the stuff away, and then THOROUGHLY drying the keyboard with an air compressor (not canned air...not enough air or pressure). Because the switches are encapsulated in a rubber boot, this probably won't do much but it's worth a try if you have access to an air compressor and want to save some money.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that every single random problem like this on Windows 7 (& Prof) is caused by my usb mouse. IDK why, but all of my problems are caused by it. My solution is by:
1. Unplug the USB mouse
2. Shut off your computer
3. Plug the mouse back in. (Make sure the computer is OFF)
4. Turn on the computer, and make sure you don't unplug the mouse :D

(Disclaimer: This might not work for you, but it does for me, so try it out)

Comment: So that's your general fix for any and all problems, regardless of what device exhibits symptoms?

Comment: If your answer were "unplugging other input devices - like mice - might help in some cases" it might be useful. Your suggestion does not relate to the question at all. Please edit your answer and read [answer] before answering next time.